# Weird optional tuple array behavior

Tags: swift

I have an array like so:

```
var array: [(NSDate?, NSData?)] = []
```

And when I use it like this:

```
array.append(NSDate(), nil)
```

The compiler gives the error `accessing members of protocol type value 'NSData' is unimplemented`

I don't understand this error, it should work right?

Comment: Your type is NSDate but you initialized an NSData object

Comment: That was a typo, updated the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is having difficulty determining the type of the tuple provided in swift when passing nil as a parameter so you must cast it to be the correct type.

```
var array: [(NSDate?, NSData?)] = []
array.append((NSDate(), nil) as (NSDate?, NSData?))
```

or

```
let t : (NSDate?, NSData?) = (NSDate(), nil)
array.append(t)
```

Comment: I don't think I am missing a set of parentheses, adding a tuple to an array requires no parentheses around said tuple, the append method takes 2 parameters for a tuple or how many elements you have.

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't support conversion like this:

```
let a:(String, Int?) = ("test", 1)
let b:(String?, Int?) = a
//                      ^ error: cannot express tuple conversion '(String, Int?)' to '(String?, Int?)'
```

The tuple type must be exactly matched to the destination type.

But, In your case, it can be considered as a bug. because this works:

```
func foo(x:(NSDate?, NSData?)) { println(x) }
foo((NSDate(), nil))
```

But this doesn't:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    func foo(x:T) { println(x) }
}

var f = Foo<(NSDate?, NSData?)>()
f.foo((NSDate(), nil))
```

The workaround would be:

```
array.append((NSDate(), nil) as (NSDate?, NSData?))
// OR
array.append((NSDate() as NSDate?, nil as NSData?))
// OR
array.append(NSDate() as NSDate?, nil as NSData?)
```

Comment: I have been finding a lot of bugs in Swift lately... Making bugreports is fun :)